# Need to capture the creation date for the folders that are listed in xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I need to capture the creation date for the folders which are listed in xml file .
Example :- The list which are fetched in foreach loop which ends with integrity6.com.
Now I have to capture the date for all the folders included in for loop.
here is my code :-

```cs
foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\\inetpub","*integrity6.com",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))               
{ 
   xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Folder", folder);
}
```

In the below code it was giving result for specific folder and directory :-

```cs
DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\\inetpub");
            
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Directory created on ", fi.CreationTime.ToLongDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Directory.GetCreationTime(String) Method**

// Get the creation time of a well-known directory.

```
DateTime dt = Directory.GetCreationTime(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

If the directory described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

The path parameter is not case-sensitive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcreationtime?view=net-5.0

Comment: NO , but I want the dates of every folder  that are included in for loop .Not for particular directory date .